# WEB API Swagger error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, swagger

Всем привет. Пытаюсь к своей API добавить swagger. Проект был создан по дефолтному шаблону Web API. Добавил свои методы, реализацию. Однако на данный момент при запуске появляется такая ошибка:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

My controller Code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using QiraTestApp.Filters;
using QiraTestApp.Interfaces;
using QiraTestApp.Models;
using QiraTestApp.Services;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace QiraTestApp.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class InvoiceController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IInvoice _invoice;
        private readonly ILogger<InvoiceController> _logger;

        public InvoiceController(ILogger<InvoiceController> logger, IInvoice invoice)
        {
            _invoice = invoice;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Invoice> GetAllInvoices([FromQuery] PaginationFilter filter, InvoiceRequest invoiceRequest)
        {
            try
            {
                return _invoice.GetAllInvoices(invoiceRequest).Skip((filter.PageNumber - 1) * filter.PageSize)
                                                              .Take(filter.PageSize)
                                                              .ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new InvoiceException($"You cannot get all Invoices, because: {ex.Message}", ex);
            }
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public Invoice GetInvoiceById(int Id)
        {
            try
            {
                return _invoice.GetInvoiceById(Id);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new InvoiceException($"We got a problem while getting Invoice: {ex.Message}", ex);
            }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public bool CreateInvoice(Invoice invoice)
        {
            try
            {
                return _invoice.CreateInvoice(invoice);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new InvoiceException($"We got a problem while creating Invoice: {ex.Message}", ex);
            }
        }

        [HttpPut]
        public bool UpdateInvoice(Invoice invoice)
        {
            try
            {
                return _invoice.UpdateInvoice(invoice);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new InvoiceException($"We got a problem while updating Invoice: {ex.Message}", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My startUp code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using QiraTestApp.Interfaces;
using QiraTestApp.Repository;
using QiraTestApp.Services;

namespace QiraTestApp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddTransient<IInvoice, CSVService>(); // DBService for .NET EF Core implementation
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "QiraTestApp", Version = "v1" });
            });
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "QiraTestApp v1"));
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Кто-то может подсказать где ошибка?

Comment: Попробуйте явно указать различные Route к методам действий GetInvoiceById и GetAllInvoices.

Answer (score 0):

Ваши методы GetAllInvoices и GetInvoiceById имеют одинаковые Route к методам. Необходимо уточнить путь хотя бы для одного из них.

Например, уточнить url метода получения всех элементов

```
[HttpGet("list")]
public IEnumerable<Invoice> GetAllInvoices([FromQuery] PaginationFilter filter, InvoiceRequest invoiceRequest)
```

или передавать id объекта не в query string

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public Invoice GetInvoiceById(int id)
```